# How to make a rectangle show around my mouse cursor wherever I move it

Tags: python, opencv

I am building a gui which will load an image, the mouse pointer should have a rectangle which when I click anywhere, it should crop the region inside the rectangle. 
I have 15+ region of interests on every image.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, please say me if so. In this case "messi.jpg" is a test image. (ESC for exit):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

img = cv2.imread("messi.jpg")
img2 = img.copy()
img3 = img2.copy()  

def tactil_sec(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global img2,img3
    if event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        img3 = img2.copy()      
        cv2.rectangle(img3,(x-30,y-30),(x+30,y+30),(255,0,0),2)

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN : 
        cv2.rectangle(img3,(x-30,y-30),(x+30,y+30),(0,0,255),2)
        img2 = img3.copy()      

cv2.namedWindow('IMAGE',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.setMouseCallback('IMAGE',tactil_sec)    
while 1:
    cv2.imshow("IMAGE",img3)
    if cv2.waitKey(20)== 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```